# Does idempotence in Rest API PUT Method require the result to be the same up to ID?

Tags: java, rest

I studied the difference between PUT and PATCH.

Of which I understood that if I use PUT, it creates the target if it doesn't exist and updates if it exists.

OK, so far no problems.

Now it's time to consider the idempotency problem.

The ID of each data is auto-generated or auto-incremented.

1. Insert data using POST.
2. Use PUT to change the data of the IDs just created.
3. No matter how many times you try 2, the result is the same.

No problem!

Now, let's assume that data is deleted in the middle.

1. Insert data using POST.
2. Use PUT to change the data of the IDs just created.
3. I just used DELETE to delete the data of changed IDs.
4. The moment you try number 2, data with a new ID is created.

Now, it can no longer be seen as the same data.

Is there any problem with idempotency in this situation?

Do I need to recreate the same resource all the way to the ID to be idempotent ok?

Or does it matter if only the valid data is the same except for the ID etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any problems with idempotency in the last situation you've described, even if the PUT from point 2. got called several times it is gonna create a new entity for the first time, and then just update the existing record. It seems rather then PUT misusage to create a new record, but to be fair, I wouldn't consider it as a problem.

In general it depends on your business case, needs etc. Normally if you try to use PUT to update non existing object, then API should return you an error about it and it is the client responsibility to determine what's next. Then depending on the business scenario you have to recreate the object with POST (and this is not same object anymore, because it will have another ID), or restore it from soft-delete state. Personally it is not a problem in any imaginable for me scenario.

Concluding - all the approaches are still perfectly idempotent if you ask me.

Comment: "it is not a problem in any imaginable for me scenario." That's right, it helped me a lot.